# Vertical menu - submenu not popping out

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and I am trying to pop up a sub menu in my vertical menu, but it is not doing it... Please see my CSS and HTML below:

```
.glossymenu{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 130px;
    border: 1px solid #9A9A9A;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
}

.glossymenu li a{
    background: white url(../images/glossyback.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
    font: bold 11px/1.5em Verdana;
    font-size: 120%;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    padding: 3px 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

// IE only. Actual menu width minus left padding of A element (10px)
* html .glossymenu li a{
    width: 130px;
}

.glossymenu li a:visited, .glossymenu li a:active{
    color: white;
}

.glossymenu li a:hover{
    background-image: url(../images/glossyback2.gif);
}


ul.sub-level {
    display: none;
}

li:hover .sub-level {
    background: #999;
    border: #fff solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
}

ul.sub-level li {
    border: none;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<div id="side">
    <ul class="glossymenu">
        <li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
        <ul class="sub-level">
            <li><a href="#"><span>Appetizer</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Beverages</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Desserts</span></a></li>              
        </ul>
        <li><a href="#">LOCATIONS</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">HOURS</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The submenu element should be inside one of the `li` elements.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/zPckp/) out.

### HTML

```
<div id="side">
    <ul class="glossymenu">
        <li><a href="#">MENU</a>       
            <ul class="sub-level">
                <li><a href="#"><span>Appetizer</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Beverages</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Desserts</span></a></li>              
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">LOCATIONS</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">HOURS</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.glossymenu{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 130px;
    border: 1px solid #9A9A9A;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    position:relative;
    top:15px;
}


.glossymenu li a{
    background: white url(../images/glossyback.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
    font: bold 11px/1.5em Verdana;
    font-size:120%;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    padding: 3px 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;

}


* html .glossymenu li a{ /*IE only. Actual menu width minus left padding of A element (10px) */
    width: 130px;
}

.glossymenu li a:visited, .glossymenu li a:active{
    color: white;
}

.glossymenu li a:hover{
    background-image: url(../images/glossyback2.gif);
}


ul.sub-level {
    display: none;
}

.glossymenu li:hover > .sub-level {
    background: #999;
    border: #fff solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
}
ul.sub-level li {
    border: none;
    float:left;
    width:150px;
}
```